# Button click not firing when leaving textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am currently making a textarea that will auto expand. This seems to work fine however the button click never seems to fire when the textarea is expanded. I am also using angularjs. Here is my code

HTML:

```
<body >
    <div my-dir></div>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.directive('myDir', function(){
    return {
        restrict:'A',
        template:'<textarea id="textarea1">'+'</textarea>' + '<button ng-click="clicked()">Click me</button><textarea id="textarea2"></textarea>',
        link:function(scope){
            scope.clicked = function(){
                 alert("click worked");
            }
        }
    }
});
```

If anybody could help me find a workaround or explain why exactly this is happening that would be greatly appreciated.

Link to codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mJrjpP

Comment: @shaggy , click on the `textarea` then click on the `button`, you wont get the `alert`.

Comment: Sorry, yes, just spotted that.

Comment: It's because the button moves on blur, so the click never happens

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the textarea is focused the button moves down a bit, and when you click the button the textareas blur event fires first, moving the button up, so the click never happens because the button moved.

The solution is to make sure the button stays put, using CSS positioning, or as noted in the comment by gyantasaurus below

```
<button ng-mousedown="clicked()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Or just use ng-mousedown

Comment: @gyantasaurus - that would work as well, as it fires before blur. The issue is really that mouseup fires after blur, and after the button has moved.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that, when the `textarea` loses focus, it resizes and the `button` moves so, if you've removed focus from the `textarea` by clicking on the `button`, the `click` event, which consists of a `mousedown` and `mouseup` event, will never fire as, when the mouse is released, the cursor is no longer over the button.

You can test this yourself by focussing on the `textarea`, clicking down on the `button`, moving your cursor to the button's new position and then releasing your mouse button.

One solution, therefore, would be simply to use the `muosedown` event, rather than the `click` event.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to move your button at the last and apply `position:fixed` to it.

```
template:'<textarea id="textarea1">'+'</textarea>' + '<textarea id="textarea2"></textarea><button class="btn" ng-click="clicked()">Click me</button>'
```

CSS:

```
.btn{
     position: fixed;
}
```

But of-course this involves changing your element's position.

Answer (score -1):

```
app.directive('myDir', function(){
  return{
    restrict:'A',
    template:'<div ng-click="clicked()"><textarea id="textarea1">'+'</textarea>' + '<button >Click me</button><textarea id="textarea2"></textarea></div>',
    link:function(scope){
        scope.clicked = function(){
          alert("click worked");
        }
    }
  }
});
```

> This is called event **event propagation** or **event bubbling**

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGpjZw

Comment: yup actually what you want can you please explain me

Comment: "*Actually I don't understand what you want*". Please ask for clarification in the comments if you don't fully understand a question.